# redux store values being passed as props to another component are empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so Im trying to access the values from the store, after updating the redux state. but the values are empty even though the store gets updated synchronously.

```
const {
    storeSimulationSelProd,
    storeApiProductsData,
    storeUpdatedInput,
    storeUpdatedResponse
  } = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.resultsCard
  } 

const addNewPanel = async () => {
    console.log(simulationSelProd)
    console.log(apiProductsData)
    console.log(updatedInput)
    console.log(updatedResponse)

    dispatch(updateResultsCard({simulationSelProd, apiProductsData, updatedInput, updatedResponse}))

      const newPanel = (
        <Panel header={"Simulation " + ((panels.length)+1)} key={(panels.length) + 1}>
          <ResultsCard options={dropdownProducts} selectedProduct={storeSimulationSelProd} productsData={storeApiProductsData} inputData={storeUpdatedInput} response={storeUpdatedResponse} showSendToResultTab={true} showData={true}/>
        </Panel>
      );
      const updatedPanels = [...panels, newPanel];
      setPanels(updatedPanels)
      dispatch(setSimulation({selectedProduct, updatedPanels}))
  }
```

I want to pass these values as props, to another component, but it is getting updated late even though the store is getting updated when i am checking synchronously. any fix for this?

Comment: why  ```useSelector``` is outside of component?

Comment: hey it is not outside, it is being used in function component Simulations, i cannot call it from inside the function addNewPanel